# How to use peanut package with angular dart to deploy project on github pages?

Tags: dart, angular-dart

It throws an error
    pub global activate peanut

Pub installs executables into $HOME/.pub-cache/bin, which is not on your path.
You can fix that by adding this to your shell's config file (.bashrc, .bash_profile, etc.):

export PATH="$PATH":"$HOME/.pub-cache/bin"

Activated peanut 3.2.1.

I have added the following paths to
.bash_profle

```
export PATH="$PATH:/Users/tusharrai/development/flutter/bin"
export PATH="$PATH:/Users/tusharrai/development/flutter/.pub-cache/bin"
export PATH="$PATH:/Users/tusharrai/development/flutter/bin/cache/dart-sdk/bin"
export PATH="$PATH:/Users/tusharrai/development/flutter/bin/cache/dart-sdk.pub-cache/bin"
```

Comment: have you tried adding `export PATH="$PATH":"$HOME/.pub-cache/bin"`?

Comment: Yes firstly I added this only but the same warning appeared

Comment: What is the shell/terminal you're using? Also, after you change the bash_profile file, assuming you're actually using bash, make sure to source it; "source ~/.bash_profile" (or just start a new shell).

Answer (score 0):

I'd avoid adding all of the pasts to your `.bash_profile`.

Instead, just run `flutter pub global run peanut`.

Comment: `flutter pub global run peanut`
No active package peanut.
pub failed (65)

Comment: `flutter pub global run peanut` Could not find a file named "pubspec.yaml" in "/Users/tusharrai/development/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/protobuf-0.10.8".
pub failed (1)

Comment: `git push origin --set-upstream gh-pages` its deploying the readme page